# Broken graphics in a compiled Android application

Tags: unity, android, architecture, augmented-reality

Why is it that when I compile this application in Unity for Android, the graphics completely break (camera image output). Maybe I need to set something special in the Player settings? I'm using [the SLAM-ARLab library on GitHub](https://github.com/Jianxff/SLAM-ARLab).

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Just from the github you linked, there are already a few extra steps you need to do for android. Have you done those? `Especially, the libc++_shared.so is required but it is not included when exported from Unity3D.` and `When first installing the app, you need to copy the Config folder to the /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.labx.arlab/files/ directory so that the app can find config files.` and `To use the app, don't forget to grant the camera permission.`

Answer (score 1):

It was a Unity bug with getting `WebCamTexture`, I changed the resolution (height and width) to 640x480, and everything worked.